# Make zod do top-level type checking on .parse() input

Tags: typescript, zod

I understand that the point of zod is to parse untrusted input data and assert that it's of a type that matches your schema.

But usually that data is coming in via web APIs that *guarantee* at least its top-level shape, like `string` or `object`.

It seems like it would make sense for zod to do this top-level type checking on `parse()`, if only to prevent silly mistakes like typos. But, seemingly, it doesn't.

As a simplified example to illustrate

```
const schema = z.string().email();
schema.parse(1); // no type error here - why?
```

It seems like `parse(1)` should have a compile time type error, because we know it's impossible that the literal `number` 1 would validate correctly at runtime. We can't do that with some random `string` input - the runtime parsing to ensure it's a valid email is required - but a *number* here seems like obvious programmer error and should not even compile.

A more practical example, which led me to ask this question

```
async function validateRequest(request: Request) {
  const someSchema = z.object({ ... })
  return someSchema.parse(request.json()) // didn't await request.json() so won't work
}
```

A silly mistake like omitting the `await` above, seems like it should be easy to catch by `someSchema.parse()` checking that I pass it an `object`, not a `Promise<object>`.

So, is there a way to enable this top-level type checking with zod?

Or is this behaviour intentional for some reason I haven't understood about zod's design?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to dig around for a way to do this in Zod but couldn't find anything convincing. I suspect that use case may not be supported out of the box. One suggestion if you want to continue doing your parsing with Zod would be to create a wrapper function with stricter types that internally calls your Zod schema.

```js
// I went for a record type because Promise<any> is assignable to object
function parseResponse(input: Record<string, unknown>) {
  const someSchema = z.object({ ... });
  return someSchema.parse(input)
}
async function validateRequest(request: Request) {
  return parseResponse(request.json()) // This will throw because now it sees the promise
}
```

### Edit:

In fact you could write this sort of helper in general like this:

```js
import { z } from "zod";
const schema = z.object({
  field: z.string(),
})

function restrict<T, Output, Def extends z.ZodTypeDef, Input = Output>(schema: z.ZodType<Output, Def, Input>) {
  return (t: T) => schema.parse(t);
}
type InferTypes<Z> = Z extends z.ZodType<infer Output, infer Defs, infer Input> ? [Output, Defs, Input] : [never, never, never];
type InferOutput<Z> = InferTypes<Z>[0];
type InferDefs<Z> = InferTypes<Z>[1];
type InferInput<Z> = InferTypes<Z>[2];

const validate = restrict<
  Record<string, unknown>,
  InferOutput<typeof schema>,
  InferDefs<typeof schema>,
  InferInput<typeof schema>
>(schema);

validate({}); // This typechecks because it's possible
async function foo(req: Request) {
  return validate(req.json()); // This has a type error.
}
```

With the only real downside being the stack of type inferring you need to do to get the generics working.

### Alternative Library

If you're open to alternative libraries, this is something supported in a relatively first class way in [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/). You can explicitly state the input and output types of your schemas, they just begin as `unknown` by default. The tradeoff is with developer experience. `io-ts` uses a functional paradigm that takes a lot of time upfront to learn.